# GTK - multiple objects signal connect

Tags: c, gtk

I have a lot of buttons in my gtk program and they have same callback function. How to avoid duplication. For example:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), data);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), data);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button3), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), data);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button4), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), data);
```

and do something like this

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(four_buttons), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), data);
```

How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
GtkButton *buttons[] = { button1, button2, button3, button4 };
for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttons[index]), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), data);
```